# MSSQL: Must declare the scalar variable @rownum

Tags: php, sql-server, variables, scalar

One of my queries is a ranking from a game.

The query is below and the error  SQL Server Management Studio shows is: "Must declare the scalar variable @rownum"

what is wrong with it?

Thanks a lot!

```
 $sql1_1     = "SET @rownum := 0";



$sql2_2       =   "SELECT * FROM (
                      SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, totalpoints, useridFB, game2points
                      FROM theuser ORDER BY game2points DESC
                      ) as result WHERE useridFB=1234";



        mssql_query($sql1_1); 
        $result = mssql_query($sql2_2);

        $row = mssql_fetch_array($result);
        $therank = $row['rank'];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using MySql syntax in SQL Server.

Use the `row_number()` function to reproduce your current logic.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY game2points DESC) AS [rank],
               totalpoints,
               useridFB,
               game2points
        FROM   theuser) AS result
WHERE  useridFB = 1234
```

Or you might want to investigate `rank` depending on how you want ties to be treated.

Comment: @user - No. You don't need `SET` or variables at all.